# Solve $x\mathrm{d}y - y\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dx$ using trig?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know there is a substitution method on here, but is it possible to solve using trig.. such as letting $y = x\cos{\theta}$?

If so could someone get me started?

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here.

Comment: LHS is a differential. RHS is not. As stated, your expression does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{x})^2}$$
$y=xu(x)$
$$u+x\frac{du}{dx}-u=\sqrt{1-u^2}$$
$$x\frac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{1-u^2}$$
This is a separable ODE :
$$\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
I suppose that you can continue.